# Is it possible to use two different configs for the same context

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In OpenGL ES 2.0, I wanted to use a 16bit config as well as 32bit config and switch between them as needed in the same context. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by config? Do you mean bits per pixel in the color buffer?

Comment: the one you request to egl subsystem after setting the attributes and make a call to eglchooseconfig with those attributes.

Comment: @JuliusCanute: I think you should try it. It would be possible for desktop GL to just make the context current to a different drawable. For GLES, all I can find is this remark for `eglMakeCurrent`: "If `draw` or `read` are not compatible with `ctx`, then an `EGL_BAD_MATCH` error is generated." But I haven't found any strict requirements for "compatibility" in this case (but I haven't looked too thoroughly either).

Comment: @derhass I didn't try it in desktop. As @"Reto Koradi" has said it didn't work for me in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OpenGL ES implementation uses EGL for its window system integration, like it is the case for example with Android, the answer is **NO**.

The signature of `eglCreateContext()` ([documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateContext.xhtml)) is the following:

```
EGLContext eglCreateContext(EGLDisplay display,
                            EGLConfig config,
                            EGLContext share_context,
                            EGLint const* attrib_list);
```

So the config of the context is specified during creation, and cannot be modified later.

Note that the config is also specified as part creating the surface. See for example `eglCreateWindowSurface()` ([documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateWindowSurface.xhtml)), which also takes an `EGLConfig` as one of the arguments. So just like you can't use multiple configs with the same contexts, you also can't use multiple configs with the same surface.

Therefore, if you want to use multiple configs, you'll need multiple contexts, as well as multiple surfaces/windows.

The only way to render to targets with different color formats within a single context is by using framebuffer objects (FBOs). FBO attachments can have color formats that are different from the format of the default framebuffer, all within a single context.

Comment: Thanks! Is switching between context a costly operation?

Comment: It can be quite expensive, yes. Definitely more than a typical OpenGL state change. It tends to be more efficient on modern hardware than it used to be.